# How can I change the radius size width and other parameters in runtime in the Update?

Tags: unity, c#

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
 
[RequireComponent(typeof(LineRenderer))]
public class DrawRadiusAroundTurret : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Range(0, 50)]
    public int segments = 50;
    [Range(0, 5)]
    public float xradius = 5;
    [Range(0, 5)]
    public float yradius = 5;
    [Range(0.1f, 5f)]
    public float width = 0.1f;
    LineRenderer line;
 
    void Start()
    {
        line = gameObject.GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
 
        line.positionCount = segments + 1;
        line.widthMultiplier = width;
        line.useWorldSpace = false;
        CreatePoints();
    }
 
    private void Update()
    {
        CreatePoints();
    }
 
    void CreatePoints()
    {
        line.widthMultiplier = width;
 
        float x;
        float y;
        float z;
 
        float angle = 20f;
 
        for (int i = 0; i < (segments + 1); i++)
        {
            x = Mathf.Sin(Mathf.Deg2Rad * angle) * xradius;
            y = Mathf.Cos(Mathf.Deg2Rad * angle) * yradius;
 
            line.SetPosition(i, new Vector3(x, 0f, y));
 
            angle += (380f / segments);
        }
    }
}
```

I tried this, At the top I added :

```
private float prevxRadius = -1.0f;
private float prevyRadius = -1.0f;
private float prevSegments = -1.0f;
```

Then in the Update , but it's never get to the CreatePoints it's only get to the first return no matter what values I change in the inspector.

```
private void Update()
    {
        if (xradius == prevxRadius) // and also check yradius and segment
            return;
        prevxRadius = xradius;
 
        if (yradius == prevyRadius) // and also check yradius and segment
            return;
        prevyRadius = yradius;
 
        if (segments == prevSegments) // and also check yradius and segment
            return;
        prevSegments = segments;
 
        CreatePoints();
    }
```

Then I tried this in the Update but it's not working either it's calling the CreatePoints after the

```
prevxRadius = xradius;
```

when I change the xradius value but the prev and current values are the same.

```
private void Update()
    {
        if (xradius == prevxRadius) // and also check yradius and segment
            return;
        prevxRadius = xradius;
        CreatePoints();
 
        if (yradius == prevyRadius) // and also check yradius and segment
            return;
        prevyRadius = yradius;
        CreatePoints();
 
        if (segments == prevSegments) // and also check yradius and segment
            return;
        prevSegments = segments;
        CreatePoints();
    }
```

The main goal is to change in real time in editor mode and runtime the values of the xradius,yradius and the segments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Myself, I'd do this in `OnValidate` if these variables are meant to be tuned in the editor. This gets called only when loading or editing the component, so it's ideal for this kind of reactive fix-up during tuning.

If these parameters can be set by scripts in-game, I'd have them call a `SetRadii(x, y)` method or something similar that can handle applying the changes on demand, rather than polling for changes every frame in your update loop.

This way, we don't need our `prev` variables at runtime at all - they can live only in the editor:

```
#if UNITY_EDITOR
float prevXRadius, prevYRadius;
int prevSegments;

void OnValidate() {
    // Can't set up our line if the user hasn't connected it yet.
    if (line == null)
        return;

    // If any values have changed, update our points.
    if(xRadius != prevXRadius || yRadius != prevYRadius || segments != prevSegments) {
        CreatePoints();

        // Cache our most recently used values.
        prevXRadius = xRadius;
        prevYRadius = yRadius;
        prevSegments = segments;
    }
}   
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working. Is that a good and logic solution ?

```
private void Update()
    {
        if (xradius != prevxRadius) // and also check yradius and segment
        {
            CreatePoints();
        }
        prevxRadius = xradius;

        if (yradius != prevyRadius) // and also check yradius and segment
        {
            CreatePoints();
        }
        prevyRadius = yradius;

        if (segments != prevSegments) // and also check yradius and segment
        {
            CreatePoints();
        }
        prevSegments = segments;
    }
```